# stored procedure, sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a `stored procedure` that will insert a new order into the

```
Order TABLE

OrderId INT
,CustomerId INT
,StoreId INT
,OrderType VARCHAR(50)
,OrderDate DATE)
```

It gives me the following error

> (Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 108 Incorrect syntax near '@StoreNumber'.) what is on line 108 is @StoreNumber = '1'.

Please help! Here is what I have so far

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spCreateOrder  (
    @CustFName varchar(10), 
    @CustLName varchar(10), 
    @OrderType Varchar(50),
    @OrderDate Date ) 
AS
Begin
    DECLARE @CustomerID INT = (SELECT CustomerID FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CustFName =       @CustFName AND CustLName = @CustLName)
    DECLARE @StoreID INT = (SELECT  StoreID FROM Store WHERE StoreID = @StoreID)

    INSERT INTO tblORDER (CustomerID, StoreID, OrderType, OrderDate)
    VALUES (@CustomerID, @StoreID, @OrderType, @OrderDate)
    DECLARE @OrderID INT = (SELECT @@IDENTITY)
    INSERT INTO tblLINE_ITEM (LineItemID, OrderID, Quantity)
    VALUES (@LineItemID, @OrderID, @Quantity)
End
```

Comment: Your syntax is SQL Server, but your question is tagged MySQL.  Please clarify.There are numerous errors in the syntax . . . unbalanced parentheses, declarations before the `begin`, keywords used as table names.  There really isn't a place to begin.

Comment: It is a sql server

Comment: There aren't 108 lines in this code nor @StoreNumber. + Code is buggy and illogical.

Answer (score 0):

Your SP doesn't really resemble your intention and also missing parameters. It would look like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spCreateOrder  (
    @CustFName varchar(10), 
    @CustLName varchar(10), 
    @OrderType Varchar(50),
    @OrderDate Date,
    @StoreID INT ) 
AS
Begin
    DECLARE @MyTable table (OrderID int NOT NULL);  
    INSERT INTO tblORDER (CustomerID, StoreID, OrderType, OrderDate)
    output inserted.OrderId into @MyTable
    SELECT CustomerID, @StoreID, @OrderType, @OrderDate 
    FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CustFName =  @CustFName AND CustLName = @CustLName;

    -- insert into tblLINE_ITEM (LineItemID, OrderID, Quantity)
    -- select ?, OrderId, ? from @MyTable;
End
```

An order hardly ever contains a single order item. You should rethink this and check basic SQL Server examples.